# Comparar elementos en una lista en Python

Tags: python, array, lista

necesito resolver un ejercicio y no sé cómo terminarlo debido a que me cuesta mucho realizar comparaciones y demás en listas. El ejercicio me pide que arme un programa que utilice el método de multiplicación egipcio, dándome de ejemplo **125x41**. El método egipcio consta de 2 columnas:

**Paso 1:**

Columna 1: Se ponen las potencias de 2 (incluido el 1) hasta llegar o acercarse al número indicado (41 en este caso). Debería quedarnos así [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32].

Columna 2: Se va multiplicando por 2 el número indicado (125 en este caso) la misma cantidad de veces que se haya potenciado la primera columna (la columna del 41). Debería quedarnos así [125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000].

**Paso 2:**

Columna 1: Ahora, tomando el último número (32), tenemos que ir sumándolo con los otros hasta que nos de 41. Como 31+16 es mayor que 41, descartamos el 16 y seguimos con el otro. Solo sumamos todos los casos que den menos de 41 hasta llegar al número exacto.

Columna 2: En esta columna solo vamos a sumar resultados específicos que tengan que ver con la primera Columna. Es decir que, para que nos de 41 en la columna 1, sumamos solo [1, 8, 32] y en la columna 2 tenemos que sumar dichos 3 números que estén en la misma posición que la otra columna [125, 1000, 4000].

**Esto nos dará el resultado final.**

Hasta ahora pude realizar el **paso 1**, pero no sé cómo realizar el **paso 2**, ¿alguien me puede ayudar? ***es urgente, muchas gracias***:

```
lista1 = []

lista2 = []

n1 = int(input("Ingrese primer número: "))

n2 = int(input("Ingrese segundo número: "))

a = 1

cont1 = 0

cont2 = 0

while a < 2:

    lista1.append(a)

    a = a + 1

    while a <= n2:

        lista1.append(a)

        a = a * 2

z = len(lista1)


while cont1 < z:

    lista2.append(n1)

    n1 = n1 * 2

    cont1 = cont1 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto sería el problema resuelto.

Tuve que crear una función para que me convierta el numero a binario y sepa que valores se les pueda sumar. Podría haberlo metido en un ciclo, pero queda más formal así.

```
# Permite determinar los valores 
# Ej: para 41
#   32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
#    1,  0, 1, 0, 0, 1      # En binario las posiciones que valen 1 se suman
#
# Nota: Devuelve tal cual muestra arriba. No la invierte porque 
# posteriormente buscaremos el valor del índice 1
def convertir_a_binario(decimal):
    lista = []
    while decimal > 1:
        resto = decimal % 2
        lista.append(resto)
        decimal = decimal // 2
    lista.append(decimal)
    return lista

lista1 = []
lista2 = []

n1 = int(input("Ingrese primer número: "))
n2 = int(input("Ingrese segundo número: "))

# Variables auxiliares para evitar que se 
# sobreescriba su valor en las sig. operaciones
aux_num1 = n1
aux_num2 = n2

a = 1
cont1 = 0
cont2 = 0
while a < 2:
    lista1.append(a)
    a = a + 1
    while a <= n2:
        lista1.append(a)
        a = a * 2
z = len(lista1)

while cont1 < z:
    lista2.append(n1)
    n1 = n1 * 2
    cont1 = cont1 + 1

# Esta lista contiene en cada posición el resto de la
# división del número dado
valores = convertir_a_binario(aux_num2)
suma = 0
for i in range(len(lista2)):
    suma = suma + lista2[i] * valores[i]    # Si valores[i] es 0 a la variable suma no se le agrega nada

print("El resultado de {} * {} es: {}".format(aux_num1, aux_num2, suma))
```

Esta instrucción sumará solo los valores de la lista que al multiplicarse por 1, en caso de que los valores sean 0 el resultado no afectará a la suma(matemática simple)

```
suma = suma + lista2[i] * valores[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la ayuda Andy, me sirvió mucho. Aunque le hice una pequeña edición y me quedó así:

```
def convertir_a_binario(decimal):

    lista = []

    while decimal > 1:

        resto = decimal % 2

        lista.append(resto)

        decimal = decimal // 2

    lista.append(decimal)

    return lista

n1 = int(input("Ingrese primer número: "))

n2 = int(input("Ingrese segundo número: "))

listan2 = convertir_a_binario(n2)

listan1 = []

while len(listan1) < len(listan2):

    listan1.append(n1)

    n1 = n1*2

resultado = 0

for posicion in range (len(listan2)):

    if listan2[posicion] == 1:

        resultado = resultado + listan1[posicion]

print (resultado)
```